# Find the limit of a step function with two different variables

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, step-function

Given the following step function:
$$
f_n(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            0 & \quad 0 \leq x < 1 - \frac{1}{n} \\
            n & \quad 1 - \frac{1}{n} \leq x < 1 \\
            0 & \quad x = 1 \\
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$
Find the following limit as **x** ∈ $ [0,1] $: $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$

It is noteworthy that while the interval for ***x*** is given here for this step function, ***n*** is the variable here. How do we calculate this limit? Do we evaluate the limits at three different intervals for **x**?

Comment: Obviously $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(1)=0$. Now, if $x\in[0,1)$ there exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x\in[0,1-\frac{1}{n})$ for all $n\geq n_0$. Then $f_n(x)=0$ for all $n\geq n_0$, which means that $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)=0$.

Comment: @R.V.N. You should post this as an answer.